# what is the best website that offer an API to scrape movie theater locations with the US

Tags: python, api, web-services

I am looking for a **website that offer a paid or free API service** to scrape all of the **movie theater locations** names, addresses, coordinates within the US?
using Python.
i have tried yelp, but its the best one, it miss out a lot

any recommendations

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) You might get a better answer at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/